# FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker Can't receive token

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, raspberry-pi, notifications

I try to receive token for FCM firebase messaging but I receive this error: FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to
register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:34839/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with
script ('http://localhost:34839/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type
('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

even my app is only android
this is my code:

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';


class FirebaseApi{
  final _firebaseMessaging =FirebaseMessaging.instance;


  Future<void> initNotifications() async{

   try{
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();


    final FCMToken= await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    print('Token: $FCMToken');
   } catch (e){
    print('error: $e');}
   } 



  }
```

and this is the main

```
Future main() async {
  //WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //await Firebase.initializeApp();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "AIzaSyD8dqZ0VEj8DiGJyuyPrdjMLkt4bdLx8YU" , 
      appId: "1:127834276317:android:e619af33b9c115c4797634", 
      messagingSenderId: "127834276317", 
      projectId: "my-surveillance-app",
      ),
  );
  

  await FirebaseApi().initNotifications();
  print('Running the app...');
  


  
  //await FirebaseApi().initNotifications();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I try to receive the token but I have this error